# wss certificate configuration

Tags: restcomm, mobicents-sip-servlets

I'd like to know if it is possible to configure a certificate for wss when using restcomm sipservlets with a keystoretype PKCS12

I found this post:
[SIPML 5 Client and SipServlets not works Using WSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686928/sipml-5-client-and-sipservlets-not-works-using-wss)

and looked to modify the suggestion to :

```
gov.nist.javax.sip.TLS_CLIENT_AUTH_TYPE=Disabled
javax.net.ssl.keystoreFile="conf/STAR_domain.pfx"
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="pkcspass"
javax.net.ssl.keystoreType="PKCS12"
```

my connector config:

```
     <Connector port="10443" 
     ipAddress = "ip.address"
     protocol="org.mobicents.servlet.sip.startup.SipProtocolHandler"
     signalingTransport="wss"/>
```

When opening a socket to this port I don't get a server hello. Meaning the cert wasn't loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Read and follow the steps at http://docs.telestax.com/sip-servlets-security/

Comment: Jean, I got to 7.2.3 I was able to enable https using the keystore/JSK file and the cert is offered during the connection. As far as the wss connector goes I cannot open socket nor does the documentation define where the wss certificate is defined. I am using restcomm-sip-servlets-4.0.75-apache-tomcat-8.0.26 and the location is under conf/server.xml am I missing something?

Comment: You configured the HTTPs connector with the certificate information, you need to do the same thing for the WSS connector. Unfortunately the configuration for that is located at the SIP Stack level, so you need to edit your conf/mss-sip-stack.properties and add 

gov.nist.javax.sip.TLS_CLIENT_AUTH_TYPE=Disabled
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=$TRUSTSTORE_FILE
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=$TRUSTSTORE_FILE
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS

Comment: It would make sense to look at the logs and see if there is any exception as well.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance Jean. Here are my configs in anyone needs a reference javax.net.ssl.keyStore=////etc/restcomm-sip-servlets-4.0.75-apache-tomcat-8.0.26/conf/myserver.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=12345
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=67890
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/security/truststore.ts
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS  Take note that unlike the server.xml connector the path here does not have to be in quotes.

Comment: Thanks for posting the final solution for others reference @100_Trying